# How do i postback?

Tags: asp.net, postback, webforms, buttonclick

I have this web application which is supposed to move rows up and down on button click, but it does only when I close the webpage and re run my program from Visual Studio.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(
                               DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataTable result = view.ToTable();
    }         
}
```

Is this all I need ?

Comment: Why did you tag this to AS.NET MVC ? This is ASP.NET webforms

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CommandName to trigger the functionality of your button clicks.

Example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a button click event. You logic is currently in the page load event, that's why its only firing once

Comment: this is what my  asp code looks like: <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnmoveup" runat="server" Text="/\" OnCommand="MoveButton_Clicked"
                                        CommandName="UP" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectID") + ";"+Eval("Priority")%>'/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                           <asp:Button ID="btnmovedown" runat="server" Text="\/" OnCommand="MoveButton_Clicked"
                                        CommandName="DOWN" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectID") + ";"+Eval("Priority")%>' />

Answer (score 0):

You could also remove the if postback which would also work but is not the recommended solution

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataTable result = view.ToTable();
}
```